# Why SwipeView components doesn't respect Item model properties?

Tags: qt, properties, qml, components, swipeview

In my application, I have an Item with Image and dimension

```
LanguageImage.qml

Item {
...
        Image
        {
            width: 100
            height:  100            
            id:imageFlag
            anchors.fill: parent
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop

        }
...
}
```

When i want to use in a SwipeView i put them like components

```
main.qml

...
   SwipeView
    {
        id:sliderImmagine
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: 0
        clip:true

        LanguageImage
        {

            id:italian
            Image
            {
                width:100
                height: 100
                source: "/image/italy.jpg"
            }
        }

        LanguageImage
        {
            id:spanish
            Image
            {
                source: "/image/spain.jpg"
            }
        }
        LanguageImage
        {
            id:french
            Image
            {
                source: "/image/france.jpg"
            }
        }

    }
```

But these Items doesn't respect dimensions that I set in Item type.
Why this?
If I force dimensions in SwipeView components it's ok.
Is there a solution or I wrong something?

Comment: hmm ... you are doing that wrongly. Actually you put an Image inside `LanguageImage` item that already has image.

Comment: Another issue that you have no layout inside the `SwipeView`. Use one of Layouts to arrange your items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide access to the Component's image you have to do something like this:

```
Item {
    property alias source: imageFlag.source
     Image {
         width: 100
         height:  100            
         id:imageFlag
         anchors.fill: parent
         fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
     }
}
```

and now you can use it as following:

```
LanguageImage {
    source: "/image/italy.jpg"
}
```